# How to plot date month year range in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to  make a chart for my website when i click button today yesterday year's etc. and then plots it on the graph.

[see images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRffn.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show your code here. **we are not code writing service**.

Comment: @VedPrakash nicely said